# ¿Como hago para buscar un elemento en un array PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo este problema con mi ejercicio que dice que tengo que buscar un elemento dentro de un array PHP y pongo array_search pero no funciona:

Este es el ejercicio:

```
$Friends = [ "Name" => [ "Peter", "Ben", "Merced", "Nicole", "Clara", "Hellen"],
"Age" => [15, 34, 23,45,34,78],
"City" => [ "Ulm", "London", "Barcelona", "Paris", "Roma", "Tallin"]];
```

Busca tu amigo teniendo presente que:

Es el más joven de todos los amigos que en el su nombre CONTIENEN la inicial de la tu nombre o apellidos.
Una vez online encontrado muestra por pantalla el su nombre, sume edad y donde vive.

y esto es lo que tengo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
$friends = ["Name"=>["Peter", "Ben", "Mercè","Nicole","Clara","Hellen"],
"Age"=>[15, 34, 23,45,34,78],
"City"=>["Ulm", "London", "Barcelona","Paris","Roma","Tallin"]];

$buscar= array_search('Peter',$friends);

echo $friends 





?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

La búsqueda no la realiza debido a que es un [array Multidimensional](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multidimensional.asp) tienes que modificar el índice de búsqueda.

El resultado de [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) te devolverá el índice de el objeto buscado, una vez que tengamos el índice de dicha búsqueda imprimimos el **array['Su subArray']['Indice']**;

```
<?php

    $friends = [
        "Name" => ["Peter", "Ben", "Mercè", "Nicole", "Clara", "Hellen"],
        "Age" => [15, 34, 23, 45, 34, 78],
        "City" => ["Ulm", "London", "Barcelona", "Paris", "Roma", "Tallin"]
    ];

    $buscar = array_search("Peter", $friends['Name']);

    $Nombre = $friends['Name'][$buscar];
    $Edad = $friends['Age'][$buscar];
    $Ciudad = $friends['City'][$buscar];

    echo 'Mi amigo ' . $Nombre. ' tiene ' . $Edad . ' años y vinve en ' . $Ciudad;


?>
```

Comment: Vale , Muchas Gracias :)

Comment: Perfecto @JosepGiner

Comment: he tenido un problema y es que me pide que lo busque mediante for y no se como hacerlo